# 2D FFT of Image and Sharpness

Tags: image-processing, fft

I'm trying to make some simply autofocus algorithm for my device and pretty confused with 2D FFT results.
As I know for now - number of high-frequency's components in 2D FFT will say me that image is more focused, than other one where 2D FFT got more low-frequency's components. And i do not know how to calculate this parameter.

I'm thinking about applying high-pass filter, but how i should choose cut-off frequency? In 1D FFT it's pretty simple to determine just looking at the picture of 1D FFT..

Comment: You will have to do a 3d plot, and based on the plot you can know where most of your energy concentrated.

Comment: If you're using Matlab, have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27314-focus-measure), based on [this](http://www.sayonics.com/publications/pertuz_PR2013.pdf) paper.

Comment: Thanks for answers. But, anyway even with 3d plot how i can get some numbers from 2D FFT for high-frequency and low-frequency? If I'm working with 1D FFT with some signal, there is mathematical equalition which can take me from bins to frequency. If i will switch (and i will) from Matlab to c# i wont be able to plot 3d graphics in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just integrating the energy in the high frequencies?
You can do that after applying High Pass filter which is equivalent of weighting high frequencies differently.